# Signed Fixed Point Numbers Inequalities in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fixed-point

I am having problems with a verilog module in which I need to check that a fixed point number is within a set range but I am having unexpected behaviour. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
reg signed [4:0] signedmaxBound =     5'sb01010; // 10
reg signed [4:0] currentValue = 5'sb00000; // 0

if (currentValue > -maxBound & currentWeight < maxBound)
    // Execute Code
```

I would just like to know if this code would accomplish the expected task (I have eliminated the issue to the module containing this code). I am not sure if -maxBound would perform the twos compliment operation correctly to represent the negative value.

Additionally I am unsure if the comparitor operators take sign into effect. i.e in this simplified format 10 is represented by 01010 and -15 is represented by 10000. 10 > -15 however 01010 is NOT larger than 10000.

Comment: should signedmaxBound be called maxBound? The minus sign there might be your issue, maybe do (0 - maxBound) and see if that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are using the bit-wise `&` operator instead of the logical `&&` operator, which has higher precedence than the relational operators. So what what you are writing gets interpreted as

```
(currentValue > ((-maxBound) & currentWeight)) < maxBound)
```

This is not what you want. You want

```
(currentValue > -maxBound && currentWeight < maxBound)
```

which gets interpreted as

```
(currentValue > (-maxBound)) && (currentWeight < maxBound)
```

And the relational operators look at the signed-ness of their operands - they both need to be signed to do a signed comparison.